# Linking tables of Jails and Jail Superintendent

Tags: sql, relational-database

I am trying to create a record system with jails, jail superintendents, judges etc. Now I need to have a table for the jails and one for the jail superintendents. I want both of them to be linked via the superintendent_id as well as the jail_id. Both of them should be autoincremented. Now I am confused that if I create the jails first, how could I put superintendent_id and if I put the superintendent_id first, how could I put the jail_id, as the foreign key has a constraint that it cannot be null. My system will have the functionality of changing the jail_superintendent later on, but what should I do when I am creating the jails in the beginning?

```
CREATE TABLE JAILS
(jail_id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
jail_name varchar(200) not null,
capacity int not null,
jail_address varchar(200) not null,
superintendent_id int not null);



CREATE TABLE SUPERINTENDENT
(superintendent_id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
username varchar(20) not null, -- password is referenced from the table USERS
name char(20) not null,
jail_id int not null
sex char(1) not null,
DOB date,
DOJ date,
phone int(10),
address varchar(200),
city char(20),
state char(20),
primary key(superintendent_id),
foreign key(username) references USERS(username)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need both the `jail_id` and the `superintendent_id` in both tables. If one jail can only have one superintendent (which seems to make sense), just have the `JAILS.superintendent_id` column and remove the `SUPERINTENDENT.jail_id` column. When you want to create a new JAIL and a SUPERINTENDENT, you create the SUPERINTENDENT first, get its id, then use it to populate the `JAIL.superintendent_id` field while creating the JAIL.

```
CREATE TABLE JAILS
(jail_id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
jail_name varchar(200) not null,
capacity int not null,
jail_address varchar(200) not null,
superintendent_id int not null);

CREATE TABLE SUPERINTENDENT
(superintendent_id int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
username varchar(20) not null, -- password is referenced from the table USERS
name char(20) not null,
sex char(1) not null,
DOB date,
DOJ date,
phone int(10),
address varchar(200),
city char(20),
state char(20),
primary key(superintendent_id),
foreign key(username) references USERS(username)
);
```